# Detecting complex signal within complex AWGN using Neyman Pearson statistic

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-detection, complex-random-variable

I need to construct a Neyman Pearson statistic for detecting a complex signal with known amplitude and unknown phase in additive complex Gaussian noise. My hypotheses are:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_0 &: R_i=W_i,& R_i \sim \mathcal{CN} (0,1) \\ 
\mathcal{H}_1 &: R_i=W_i + A,&R_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(A,1)
\end{align}

alternatively,

\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}_0 &: R_i=W_i,& W_i \sim \mathcal{CN} (0,1) \\ 
\mathcal{H}_1 &: R_i -A=W_i,&W_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)
\end{align}

where $A = A_0e^{j\theta_0}$ is the signal, and $i=1,2,...N$. The signal A occurs over a known region of the data, say $m_1$ to $m_2$, where $ 0 \leq m_1 \lt N, m_1 \lt m_2 \leq N$ and  as such the statistical model is to be applied only over that region.

My first steps are marginalizing the nuisance parameters $\theta_0$, and calculating the statistic, assuming $\theta_0 \sim \mathcal{U}(0,2\pi)$:

$$ \frac{f(\mathbf r|H_1)}{f(\mathbf r|H_0)} = \frac{\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{N}\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{\pi} \exp{\left(-\lVert r_i - A_0e^{j\theta_0}\rVert^2\right)}\,\mathrm d\theta_0 }{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\pi} \exp{\left(-\lVert r_i\rVert^2\right)}}\text,$$

with $\mathbf r=(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_N)$ being the observation.

Is my construction correct? I can't see how to proceed from here that will allow me to construct a statistic to compare against a threshold. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your formulation of $H_1$, *what* is circularly-symmetric normal? $A_i$ or $(Y_i-A_i)$? Is it possible that your $A_i=A_0e^{i\theta_0}$ is missing an imaginary unit ($j$) in the exponent? $Y_i$ and $A_i$ are independent, right?

Comment: Isn't there an integral sign missing in $f(Y|H_0)$? The $\mathrm d\theta_0$ in your integral should be after the exponential, seeing that this is the integrand?

Comment: Fixed the question. Yes the whole thing is under the integral sign. And I don't see why $f(Y|H_0)$ should have an integral, since it does not have the $\theta_0$ parameter. $Y_i -A_i$ is the circular symmetric variable here.

Comment: While you're right about the integral, this raises a lot of questions. So, let's start small: what is the relationship of the elements in $Y$? I think there's still too much confusion in your notation. For example, your $f(Y|H_1)$ can only be the product of densities of $Y_i-A_i$ if these are independent. But in that case, there's nothing to be done here: in both you $H_0$ and $H_1$ you get the exact same statistic, iid $~\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$, and Neyman-Pearson can't do anything about that.

Comment: and really, what's being integrated here? Integrating over $\frac1{2\pi}$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ makes little sense, but it's exactly what your integral does, the way it's written.

Comment: The integration is over $P(\theta) = 1/(2\pi)$, which is the distribution assumed for $\theta$. I am using $P(D|H) = \int d\theta p(\theta) f(D|H, \theta)$

Comment: integrating a 1-D density itself over its region of definition will always yield 1 (that's part of the definition of density), really not sure what we're doing here :(

Comment: It won't, since the exponential in the integrand is also a function of $\theta_0$. Sorry if the question is misleading.

Comment: your exponential is, as I've tried to point out twice, currently not the integrand :) But let me fix the formula real quick, I guess this is just my notational preference, not your fault.

Comment: I took the slightly brazen step of changing your notation, Razor, to reduce my own confusion (again, not your fault!) with what $Y$, $Y_i$ and $y_i$ are. Could you check whether this edit reflects your intent, and if not, use the "rollback" function of the edit history to restore your original notation? (or, refine it. It's your question- I feel bad for twiddling around with it)

Comment: It looks fine, thanks.

Comment: Cool, but then I'm still really confused about this: $\mathcal{H}_1 : R_i=Y_i - A_i,\quad R_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$. Since $Y_i\sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$, and  $Y_i$ and $-A_i$ are independent, the only possible variance of $A_i$ would be 0.

Comment: Right. That's because $A_i$ is a constant signal with amplitude A_0 and phase \theta_0 across all realizations. It's just that the phase of the signal is not known a priori.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaah! $A_i= A_{i-1}\forall i$!! Ok, let's remove the index then!

Comment: But then your $\mathcal{CN}$ isn't 0-mean anymore - the new mean is $-A$, i.e. $R_i \sim\mathcal{CN}(-A,1)$.

Comment: I thought I made it clear with the definition of A_i = A_0e^{j\theta_0}, the index is there to denote it's a discrete signal. To answer your other question, the mean is indeed zero over the "interesting" region of the signal, and elsewhere you are right. But then again, it is known where the signal occurs, if at all, so it makes zero sense to talk about non-interesting regions of the data, and hence the mean is always zero if the signal is present, i.e under H_1.

Comment: I didn't follow that comment at all; $A_i$ is a constant, it's not really "discrete". If the mean of a sum is zero, then you're adding zero to your zero-mean noise, if you're adding a constant. So, either, $A_i$ is not a constant, it is zero, or (Y_i-A_i) is not zero-mean. There's a contradiction in there!

Comment: I have edited the question in response to your previous comment, please see if that clarifies your doubts.

Comment: No, that changes nothing at all. When you add a constant to a zero-mean variable, the sum isn't zero-mean anymore. It's that simple!

Comment: If you subtract the constant equivalently from your RV, it stands to reason that the residual is just WGN.

Comment: yes, but you're not doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110120/discussion-between-razor-and-marcus-muller).